# Multiple copies of timer programs inserted by AJAX: how to assure that only one copy is running

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an HTML file `product.html` which is inserted into a div in another HTML file using AJAX (by button clicking). There is a timer in `product.html` as follows:

`product.html`:

```
<!-- HTML stuff -->
...

Bid time of the product: <div id="displayTime"></div>

...
<!-- HTML stuff -->


<div id="testChange">
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

  function updateTime() {
    var newContent = $("#testChange").html();
    if (newContent != oldContent) {  // If the content of "testChange" changes, stop the timer
      return;
    }
    timeStr = ...   // prepare the time for display
    $("#displayTime").html(timeStr);
    setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
  }

  function startUpdatingTime() {
    oldContent = $("#testChange").html();
    updateTime();
  }

 startUpdatingTime();

</script>
</div>
```

When I click the button such that file `product.html` gets inserted by AJAX into the div of another HTML. The timer runs OK. However, when I click the button again, there are apparently two copies of the timers running. If I click again, there will be multiple copies of the timers running. The `displayTime` div is flickering because so many timers are trying to update it. My question: how do I check if there is already a timer running so that there is no need to run a new one. Or how do I stop the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `clearTimeout` as posted below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var timeout, oldContent;

  function updateTime() {
    var newContent = $("#testChange").html();
    if (newContent != oldContent) {  // If the content of "testChange" changes, stop the timer
      return;
    }
    timeStr = ...   // prepare the time for display
    $("#displayTime").html(timeStr);

    if (timeout){
       window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = window.setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
  }

  function startUpdatingTime() {
    oldContent = $("#testChange").html();
    updateTime();
  }

 startUpdatingTime();

});
```